# How do I keep a PNG texture's alpha channel transparent after exporting as an .OBJ?

Tags: transparency

This is what my model looks like [without shaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WReUD.png).

This is what it looks like [with shaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed46T.jpg).

The facial features are on the block that is covering the face, and shaders need to be added to make the PNG texture's alpha channel transparent.

When I export as an .OBJ to put into Element 3D (After Effects), [the facial features block isn't transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtEt8.png).

Am I able to render this model correctly as an .OBJ? I'm new to Blender so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please make the images visible in your post, not as links,like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853

Comment: Shaders don't translate across different formats. read https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/98444